# How to create this type of interactive filter/slicer in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, report

*Sorry for the vague title, but I really don't know how's this thing called and I could not even find any reference to it on the internet.*

I was browsing some of my older Excel reports and I stumbled upon this interesting filter/slicer thingy, that allows me to view the table data on multiple levels.

[image]

Issue is, I for one can't remember how I managed to create this as there's nothing in the pane that would indicate a similar feature.

Any idea how to replicate this and what is this called?

Comment: Data Tab -> Outline, beyond that I cannot help you

Comment: beyond that.. just share what you had tried.. and stuck at. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot How can I share what I tried when I explicitly said I don't know what's that feature called and I don't remember how to create it. What do you want me to record a video of myself looking at the Excel panes?

Comment: With rows selected, `CTRL+SHIFT+RIGHT` to create a group, and `CTRL+SHIFT+LEFT` to remove a group. Or go into the Data tab, and find the buttons for it.   Actually, that's what I found online, but my excel says `ALT+SHIFT+RIGHT` and `ALT+SHIFT+LEFT`. It's grouping rows anyway.

Comment: What I meant is.. [ Data -> Outline ] is the location of the command icons is.. the excel help keyword is "Outline (group) data in a worksheet" ... || After you had tried it on your own data.. you may share where you're stuck at (and edit the question).. (We can only go beyond if there is a sample data/Output planned.. ) || Just to answer " How to create .. filter/slicer in Excel? " @cybernetic.nomad comment is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Actually @ChristoferWeber (almost) got it right.*
You can [group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.group) and ungroup data.

The standard shortcuts

- to group data: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>
- to ungroup data: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd>

Alternatively you can go to dat and `Group` / `Ungroup`

[image]

Perhaps more useful and interesting is the **`Subtotal`** function, which can group data by their type and create something akin to a pivot table that is interactive on multiple layers *(like picture I linked in my question)*

[image]